# Blender and OCIO - Texture bug or what I do wrong?

Tags: texturing, compositing-nodes, color, color-management

my first question here is rather technical.
Because of my interest in color management and ACES I am writing articles on my website about this topic. For 3D related tests I am using Blender.

So I am working in Blender with the OCIO environment variable set.

I checked the following what is best seen on screenshots and would like to know what I do wrong or there is a bug.

I marked the important areas on the screenshots from the Blender Compositor (which seems to work fine) and the Shading/ImageViewer which seems to ignore a part of the colorspace transform or clamp values as long as the texture is not a EXR file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
Thanks